# How to call something before React app refresh or reload by create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm developing a React app using create-react-app. The good thing is every time I save my changes, the app/page will automatically reload or refresh. The bad thing is my app locks some resources on the server, every auto reload will make those resources still in locked status so my app can't use it. Is there a way to call some types of destructor to release the lock before the page refreshes?

Comment: I'll look a solving this issue in the server. As-is, where there a way to perform a series of action before hot reloading (which may or may not require eject the create-react-app); I don't see the issue going away when your app is released to users and they reload it in their browsers.